# Оценка качества кластеризации

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, теория, кластеризация

Подскажите пожалуйста. Если стоит задача кластеризации нескольких тысяч поисковых запросов ( то есть коротких предложений в 2-5 слов, не обязательно русских ) Каким образом оценить качество реализованного подхода (какую метрику использовать, если нету размеченных данных с определенными кластерами)? И каким образом лучше подобрать количество кластеров?

Comment: ищи в сети полно. метрику какую использовать ( используй в совокупности несколько метрик) потому что сложно сказать какая из метрик в твоем случае будет лучше работать. Нужно тестировать и смотреть

Answer (score 1):

по-моему на данный вопрос невозможно дать однозначный ответ. Различные алгоритмы кластеризации по разному кластеризируют один и тот же дата сет.

[Пример из `SciKit-Learn` документации](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#overview-of-clustering-methods) - все алгоритмы обрабатывали одинаковые наборы входных данных. Строки представляют набор данных, столбцы - различные алгоритмы кластеризации.

Различные алгоритмы выдают разные результаты для разных данных.

PS я не знаю какой алгоритм лучше подойдет для ваших данных.

Answer (score 0):

Иван, вчера или позавчера вы задали аналогичный вопрос.

[Кластеризация поисковых запросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/896990/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2/897142#897142)

В своем ответе на него я дал вам кучу ссылок, просмотрев (хотя-бы бегло) которые вы бы нашли ответы на ваши вопросы.  И про количество кластеров, и про метрики, и даже про способы сравнения алгоритмов. Вы их просмотрели и так и не смогли найти ответы? Или вы желали, что вам тут вот прямо в форуме выложили готовые решения? В чем причина практически дублирования вопроса?

Comment: Дело, наверное, в разнице уровня понимания. На любой вопрос можно дать много ссылок, они полезные, за них спасибо. Но они охватывают всю конкретную область знаний и ясности, что из алгоритмов лучше использовать, при их беглом прочтении, не дают. Да, из них я узнал еще про несколько алгоритмов и метрик качества алгоритмов. Но опыта не хватает, чтобы выбрать что-то и корректно оценить результат. Поэтому и спросил, с расчетом, что люди, которые уже работали с чем-то похожим скажут "я бы использовал это, оценил так-то и потом добавил еще вот это, а вообще обычно здесь использую то-то".

Comment: Т.е. вы ожидаете "рібу, а не сети"  -  готовое, кеи-то подготовленное для вас решение, а не хотите самому разобраться в вопросе. Ну, каждому свое. Кстати,, а что будет, если вам тут дадут готовое решение, вы его доверчиво примете, но оно по факту окажутся ошибочными? Или того худе - посоветует пол десятка разных подходов. Как без собственного понимания выбрать правильно?